# Idiomatic way to sum multiple vectors in Clojure

Tags: vector, clojure, iteration

**Problem:** I've got a collection of vectors or lists which I would like to find an idiomatic way to sum onto an existing vector possibly with uneven sized vectors. 
Contrived example showing the setup:

```
=>(def collated-list [2 3 4 5 6 7 8])
=>(def lists-to-add (partition-all 3 collatedlist))
=>(def base-list [1 1 1])
```

I'd like the result to sum the broken down collated lists onto the `base-list`, for example, the first item would be `1 + 2 + 5 + 8` and so on.

**What I've tried:** I've tried a `map` and a `for` loop in couple of different ways but I seem to encounter either problems with Lazy Sequencing or problems of trying to add an `Integer` to a `Vector`.

These are my first experiments with Clojure so it's almost certainly me mis-understanding functional iteration here.

Thanks

Comment: See also the recent [Changing map behaviour in Clojure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033678/changing-map-behaviour-in-clojure) question which deals with `map`-with-padding in the general case (i.e. with an arbitrary function, number of lists and padding element).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it'll be much easier if lists-to-add contains lists of even length, so use `partition` instead of `partition-all`:

```
(def lists-to-add (partition 3 3 '(0 0) collated-list))
```

And then you can do the summing with `map` and recursion:

```
(defn sum-lists [base-lists lists-to-add]
    (reduce #(map + %1 %2) base-list lists-to-add))
```

Comment: Or even simpler (apply map + base-list lists-to-add)

Comment: Thanks liwp and to @Roman Bataev for the delightfully simple version.

Comment: You can also use `(repeat 0)` as the `pad` argument to `partition` to avoid spelling out the exact number of zeros required.

Answer (score 0):

```
; List of list
(def lst (partition 5 (range 200)))

; Base list
(def base [1 1 1 1 1])

; Sum operation
(apply map (fn [& args] (apply + args) ) base lst)
```

Comment: This won't work properly with uneven sized vectors. Besides, you could just use + instead of (fn [& args] (apply + args) )